# Configuration to ignore certain folders by dependabot.yml

Tags: github, dependabot

I have a large monorepo.

I am only interested in the security updates of say 4 out of 10 folders (each folder is a project).

If I use a `dependabot.yaml` like this

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/folder1"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    # Disable version updates for npm dependencies
    open-pull-requests-limit: 0
  - package-ecosystem: "go"
    directory: "/folder2"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    # Disable version updates for go dependencies
    open-pull-requests-limit: 0
.
.
```

so that it includes only the folders of interest, will it automatically ignore the rest of the folders or does it need an explicit `ignore` for them?